# Hover function not working on Rapael.js objects from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Using Raphael.js 2.1.0 I am trying to create circle objects on the Canvas from an array of coordinates by using this code:

```
var map = Raphael('canvas', 500, 500);
var coords = [ [150,50], [20,85], [350,95] ];
var circle;
for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
  circle = map.circle(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 20);
  circle.toFront();
  circle.attr({
      fill: '#98ED00',
      translation: "4,4",
      stroke: '#FFF',
      'stroke-width': 4,
      opacity: 1,
  });
}

  circle.hover(
  function () {
      circle.animate({
          fill: 'red',
          opacity: 1,
          map: 30,
              'stroke-width': 4
      }, 300);
  }, function () {
      circle.animate({
           fill: '#98ED00',
          opacity: 1,
              'stroke-width': 4,
          map: 20
      }, 300);

  });
```

but the hover function ONLY functioning on the LAST created object! How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is which circle are you referencing when you call 'circle.glow()', as you have 3 ?

The circle var gets overwritten each time, so the handler just gets attached to the last one.

To get around this, there's a few different ways. You could create an array for the circles and add a hover handler to each one. Or you could create a closure which is the example below.  It depends if you need to do anything with it later that may affect the solution...

```
var map = Raphael('canvas', 500, 500);
var coords = [ [150,50], [20,85], [350,95] ];

for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
    (function() {
      var circle;
      circle = map.circle(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 20);
      circle.toFront();
      circle.attr({
         fill: '#98ED00',
          translation: "4,4",
          stroke: '#FFF',
         'stroke-width': 4,
         opacity: 1,
     });
     circle.hover(
       function () {
         circle.animate({
              fill: 'red',
              opacity: 1,
              map: 30,
              'stroke-width': 4
          }, 300)
         }, function () {
           circle.animate({
               fill: '#98ED00',
               opacity: 1,
              'stroke-width': 4,
              map: 20
          }, 300)
         }    );
    })();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HVh9E/2/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the hover event binding should be inside the for loop. That way each object is bound after it is created .. .. before moving to the next one.

```
var map = Raphael('canvas', 500, 500);
var coords = [ [150,50], [20,85], [350,95] ];
var circle;
for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
  circle = map.circle(coords[i][0], coords[i][1], 20);
  circle.toFront();
  circle.attr({
      fill: '#98ED00',
      translation: "4,4",
      stroke: '#FFF',
      'stroke-width': 4,
      opacity: 1,
  });

  circle.hover(
  function () {
      circle.animate({
          fill: 'red',
          opacity: 1,
          map: 30,
              'stroke-width': 4
      }, 300);
  }, function () {
      circle.animate({
           fill: '#98ED00',
          opacity: 1,
              'stroke-width': 4,
          map: 20
      }, 300);

  });
}
```

Comment: This solution wouldn't work as is, but with a small modification of changing the circle.animate() call inside the hover handler to this.animate(), this should then work, as the functions will know which correct element to animate. This would then possibly be prererable to my other solution. http://jsfiddle.net/6aWE6/ If you amend the answer a bit I'll give an upvote.